# How to use callback to send back data to previous ViewController

Tags: swift

I have 2 ViewControllers like this:

[image]

I want when I press button in ViewController will present to ViewController2. Then when I input the text in TextField and press Back Button in ViewController2, will send that text to button in ViewController1.

I can solve this with delegate or using reference the class ViewController in ViewController2. (You can see with my comment code)

But now I want to use CallBack to send back data.

How to do this:

Here is ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    var myString = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        button.setTitle(myString, forState: .Normal)
    }
    @IBAction func goToViewController2(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
//        vc2.vc1 = self
        presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And ViewController2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
//    var vc1: ViewController?
    var callback: ((String) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        callback!(textField.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func backToViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
//        vc1?.myString = textField.text!
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And I don't want to use with completion block in dismiss function, I just want to use my own callback method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `vc1`, set `vc2`'s callback property before presenting it:

```
@IBAction func goToViewController2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
    vc2.callback = { <Put your callback code here...> }
    presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And then, in `vc2` call the callback function before dismissing the view controller:

```
@IBAction func backToViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    callback?(textfield.text!)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Nice, vc2.callback = ({ string in
            self.myString = string
        })
Thanks.